# NHibernate QueryOver remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm working on a feed system where I need to show a certain number of feeds and then showing more by clicking a "Load more" button.

So I've defined a number of rows to fetch from the database (take) and everytime I push the Load More button I send the skip number (the number of feeds already shown). The problem is that I'm getting duplicated rows with my query.

I want to use something like DISTINCT to skip those duplicates, so I've read I should use TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity), but that function works code-side and not db-side, so, when I try to apply skip and take, the number of feeds is wrong. Let's say I have 5 feeds, but I got 2 duplicates so when I apply the take function, the result just have 4 feeds.

This is my code, I appreciate any help

```
public IList<FeedBO> GetFeedsByUserSkills(int companyId, List<SkillBO> userSkills, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
    {
        FeedSkillBO feedSkillAlias = null;
        var query = session.QueryOver<FeedBO>()
               .JoinAlias(x => x.FeedSkills, () => feedSkillAlias)
               .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Restrictions.Conjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.On(() => feedSkillAlias.Skill).IsIn(userSkills))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Company.Id", companyId)))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Scope", Constants.FEED_SCOPE_GLOBAL)))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

        if (skip.HasValue) query.Skip(skip.Value);
        if (take.HasValue) query.Take(take.Value);

        var sql = GetGeneratedSql(query);

        return query.OrderBy(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Property("CreationDate")).Desc.List();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I gave up with Transform and I'm now trying to do a group by:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<FeedBO>()
               .JoinAlias(x => x.FeedSkills, () => feedSkillAlias)
               .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Restrictions.Conjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.On(() => feedSkillAlias.Skill).IsIn(userSkills))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Company.Id", companyId)))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Scope", Constants.FEED_SCOPE_GLOBAL)))
                .Select(
                    Projections.Distinct(
                        Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Id).As("Id"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Uuid).As("Uuid"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Title).As("Title"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Content).As("Content"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Link).As("Link"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.ImagePreview).As("ImagePreview"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Scope).As("Scope"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.EventDate).As("EventDate"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.CreationDate).As("CreationDate"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.CreationUser).As("CreationUser"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Active).As("Active"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Company).As("Company"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.FeedSkills).As("FeedSkills"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property<FeedBO>(x => x.Likes).As("Likes"))
                    )
                ).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBeanConstructor(typeof(FeedBO).GetConstructors().First()))
                .OrderBy(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Property("CreationDate")).Desc;

        if (skip.HasValue) query.Skip(skip.Value);
        if (take.HasValue) query.Take(take.Value);
```

And this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT distinct this_.id as y0_, this_.uuid as y1_, this_.title as y2_, this_.content as y3_, this_.link as y4_, this_.image_preview as y5_, this_.scope as y6_, this_.event_date as y7_, this_.creation_date as y8_, this_.creation_user_id as y9_, this_.active as y10_, this_.company_id as y11_, this_.id as y12_, this_.id as y12_ 
FROM dbo.FEED this_ inner join dbo.FEED_SKILL feedskilla1_ on this_.id=feedskilla1_.feed_id 
WHERE ((feedskilla1_.skill_id in (2, 1, 24) and this_.company_id = 1) or this_.scope = 'global') 
ORDER BY this_.creation_date desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Which works if I run it directly in the db, but when I run the program, it throws this exception

> index was outside the bounds of the array

I don't know what to do, help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Import nHibernate.Linq
Replace QueryOver<> with Query<> which implements System.Linq and simplify your query.

You then would simply admin .Distinct() to your linq. No need to get into the unnecessary complexity!

Note that you can only join relations that you have defined in mapping.

Comment: How can you do the joinAlias in Query? I need the distinct applies at db level and not to the result list.

Comment: I assume you are mapping the relation you wish to join such as FeedBO.Company. you would simple add your condition in a .Where() which will be mapped to sql query condition

Comment: The .IsIn doesn't work i think, you can instead check for x.FeedSkills.Any(y => userSkillsIdArray.Contains(y.Skill.Id)))

Comment: You can, worst case,  execute as SQL query